# How do I bind string to a label content in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I am currently working on a project, I'm mainly focused on back-end and I know that this XAML code is not good practice. I am not really used to INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and I'm really having hard time seeing a mistake. When I debug program, TourName is not empty, it gets value from liveTourAppointment.tour.name; but Label in window stays empty when I run it

Here is what I tried:

XAML Code:

```
    <Grid>
        
        <Label x:Name ="Label" Content="{Binding Path=TourName}" Margin="82,44,579,354"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And Code behind is here:

```
    public partial class LiveTourWin : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TourAppointment liveTourAppointment { get; set; }
        
        private string _tourName =".";
        public string TourName
        {
            get { return _tourName; }
            set
            {
                {
                    if (value != _tourName)
                    {
                        _tourName = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TourName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private readonly TourAppointmentController _tourAppointmentController;
        public LiveTourWin(int guideId)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            _tourAppointmentController = new TourAppointmentController();
            

            liveTourAppointment = _tourAppointmentController.GetLiveTour(guideId);
            this.TourName = liveTourAppointment.tour.name;
            
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the code looks strange it works as it should (checked on simple project). The label is set. The margins though, were so big, that the label was almost completely obscured (not sure how your window is set)

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is find.  The issue you have is the margins.  You are doing some absolute settings.  Try not to do that.   Each object in the "Window" such as your grid object take up the full space available.  Much like that of a browser.  You resize the window and things typically auto-adjust, columns and such.

To help this, allocate space in your window and auto-adjust to allow for shrink/expand.  Now, how to do it.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Example of 3 equally sized columns -->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- multiple rows with different fixed heights.
         The last row with "*" means take up all unused space for the rest -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Place whatever controls at specific row/column locations -->
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" (rest of label content />
</Grid>
```

Additionally you can allocate a minimum size PLUS "*" to allow stretching based on available such as below.  This has 3 columns.  The first is fixed at 120 pixels, but the remaining two columns have a pre-defined minmum, but since the "*" is on both, they can stretch or shrink based on available.  So, say the window is 800 wide.  The first remains 120, second and third get 200 and 350 each which is a total of 670 leaving 130 remaining.  Since TWO columns have the "*", each column would get an additional width of 65.  Same applies for row definitions.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="350*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

There are other types of controls, StackPanels, DockPanels, etc that allow other formatting and alignment options.

So, your binding works, but if you give it a designated location that is pre-allocated for space as you will ultimately prepare your user interface, make what works for you and not worry about "fixed" margins and such.

Additional note, for LABELS, because they are typically generated once up front, you MAY need to add to the binding clause such as

```
 <Label x:Name ="Label" Content="{Binding Path=TourName, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
```